All vscode `Dev Containers: xxx` commands fail with "stream is closed" after Win11 did a "Boot Device Not Found" then Startup Repair
I'm all out of ideas. I rebooted the PC one day then half way through startup, like practically to the point it should show the login screen, it unexpectedly threw a "Boot Device Not Found". It was already at the Win logo booting before I walked away for coffee, but when I came back there was just the dreaded boot message coming in as a huge surprise.
On next boot it did startup repair & fixed itself, but it notably appeared to have rolled back a few days & broke anything that might have done updates in those lost days.     I had to do some SFC /scannow & DISM -RestoreHealth to get things like the Store & built in programs like snipping-tool working again (would give "not a valid win32 program").  Chrome, Slack, Windhawk, and various apps installed through the Store were others that needed full reinstall.
That was 5days ago. Since then, everything seems to be working except vscode's ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers extension which always throws stream is closed errors when attempting to use it.
What I've tried so far (with reboots between each point):

Using Revo Uninstaller & Voidtools Everything to track down any remnants, I completely uninstalled & wiped:

VSCode + Profiles + extensions
Kubernetes (after doing Factory Reset in its menu)
Rancher Desktop (after doing Factory Reset in its menu)
Docker Desktop & anything with docker in the name


Uninstalled Ubuntu and all other WSL distros
Wiped all of WSL
Uninstalled Windows Subsystem for Linux & Virtual Machine Platform windows features

I then reinstalled & setup everything in reverse order. Surprisingly, the VSCode Docker extension ms-azuretools.vscode-docker actually now does work & shows containers, images, networks, & volumes - this has never worked before & has always stumped me.
But I'm still getting the same stream is closed error when I try to interact with any container using the ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers extension. I've also tried everything VSCode's Copilot Chat suggested to no avail.
Are there any Windows services that perhaps facilitate communication with remote containers?  One that's supposed to provide some kind of stream/pipe?
I really don't want to reinstall Windows... I'm grandfathered in to Windows Subsystem for Android. But I don't know what else I can do except that. I definitely won't be doing it without first buying another SSD, to avoid nuking the current one.
[Window Title]
Visual Studio Code

[Main Instruction]
Command 'Dev Containers: Open Folder in Container...' resulted in an error

[Content]
stream is closed

[OK]

2024-10-08 22:12:45.936 [error] Error: stream is closed
    at c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:30:3813
    at o (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:30:1926)
    at EventEmitter.MR.e.<computed> [as setBaseEnv] (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:30:1684)
    at c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:99:274
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.setBaseEnv (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:99:243)
    at vb (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:124:3235)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at st (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:331:2237)
    at no (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:387:1100)
    at m (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:413:11417)
    at T0.h (file:///c:/Program%20Files/Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:114:32837) 
  remote-containers.rebuildAndReopenInContainer {
    "value":"ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers",
    "_lower":"ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers"
  }
2024-10-08 22:12:53.579 [error] Error: stream is closed


[1800972 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d rancher-desktop -e /bin/sh -c cd '/mnt/d/appliedsystems/us-rating/entryform' && /bin/sh
[1800978 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[1801004 ms] root
[1801004 ms] 
[1801005 ms] Start: Run in host:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'root' || grep -E '^root|^[^:]*:[^:]*:root:' /etc/passwd || true)
[1801059 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[1801060 ms] /root
[1801060 ms] 
[1801060 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/server/node'
[1801060 ms] 
[1801061 ms] Exit code 1
[1801061 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode/cli/servers/Stable-e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/server/node'
[1801061 ms] 
[1801062 ms] Exit code 1
[1801062 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode-server/bin/e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/node'
[1801062 ms] 
[1801062 ms] 
[1801063 ms] Exit code 1
[1801063 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/node'
[1801063 ms] 
[1801064 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/node_modules/node-pty/package.json'
[1801064 ms] 
[1801064 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.388.0.js'
[1801065 ms] 
[1801065 ms] Host server: /bin/sh: /root/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/e10f2369d0d9614a452462f2e01cdc4aa9486296/node: not found
[1801065 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[1801065 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[1801066 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/sh
[1801069 ms] Error reading shell environment.
[1801069 ms] Error: stream ended with:0 but wanted:9
    at l (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:22149)
    at c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:22330
    at s (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:30:5371)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Derek\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.388.0\dist\extension\extension.js:30:5541)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[1801070 ms] Host server terminated (code: 127, signal: null).


Alright looking like I won't have to reinstall Windows.
I created a new Windows User & it works there. No idea what's corrupt on my Windows Account.
EDIT:  That wasn't it.  Issue came back after syncing my vscode profile. The issue was Dev > Containers: Execute in WSLDistro dev.containers.executeInWSLDistro setting needs to be blank/empty:

Also RancherDesktop fails to setup Kubernetes unless you have already set Kubernetes up earlier with DockerDesktop.
